# no css formatting in jquery listview ajax

Tags: css, ajax, listview, jquery-mobile

I am fairly new to jquery all together.  Basically what I have done is made a dynamic gallery populated from images retrieved from an ajax call.  The images are appended to a unordered list and supposed to receive special css formatting specific to the image gallery, other ul lists are untouched.  Everything works great, however when I view the gallery, the proper css formatting is not rendered on the images.  I have searched all over stackoverflow and tried many of the options presented to similar problems including **.listview('refresh');** and after an ajax **complete:** as well as some other solutions.  Nothing is working.  If I navigate away from the page and come back, the formatting is applied.  Here is the following code I am working with.

**Link to Gallery**

```
$('ul#fieldList').append('<li id="albums"><a href="#Gallery1?" onClick="GetUserPhotos('+value.album_id+'); return false;"><img src="images/1.jpg"><h3>'+value.name+'</h3><p>'+value.description+'</p></a><div class="ui-li-count">'+value.count+' Images</div></li>');
```

**onClick Function**

```
function GetUserPhotos(albumid) {

    console.log("Get User Photos Function Ran");
    var get_user_photos_album_id = albumid;
    var get_user_photos_client_id = window.localStorage.getItem("client_id");
    var get_user_photos_user_id = window.localStorage.getItem("user_id");
    console.log("Assign Variables from local storage");
    var formData = {
        user_id: get_user_photos_user_id,
        client_id: get_user_photos_client_id,
        album_id: get_user_photos_album_id
    }; //Array 

    $.ajax({
        url: "client_photos.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        async: "false",
        success: function (data) {
            $("ul#photosList li#photos").remove();
            $("#test1").html('');
            //data - response from server
            var PhotoData = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log("PhotoData json data parsed");
            $("ul#fieldList li#albums").remove();
            $.each(PhotoData, function (key, value) {
                $('ul#photosList').append('<li id="photos"><a rel="' + value.album + '" href="http://www.myphotoshootapp.com/cms/uploads/' + value.client_id + '/' + value.album + '/' + value.id + '.' + value.ext + '" class="swipebox" title="' + value.fullname + '""><img src="http://www.myphotoshootapp.com/cms/uploads/thumbs/' + value.client_id + '/' + value.album + '/' + value.id + '.' + value.ext + '" alt="' + value.fullname + '" /></a></li>');
            });
            Swipe();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#ul#photosList').listview('create');
            $.mobile.changePage("#Gallery1");
        }
    });
}
```

**DIV Item's Are Added To**

```
<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="photosList">
     <li id="title">Photos</li>
     <div class="main" id="test1"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**And CSS**

```
li#photos { float: left !important; width: 33.33333333% !important; }
li#photos a { display: block !important; margin: 5px !important; border: 1px solid #3c3c3c !important; }
li#photos img { display: block !important; width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
```

As I said, I am pretty new to this and learning as I go, I have learned so much from reading a lot of other questions here but this one I can not figure out.  Thanks for the help.

On the first visit, a bunch of extra classes like ui-btn, ui-btn-icon-right, ui-li-has-arrow, ui-li, ui-li-has-thumb, ui-btn-up-c are being added and the second time, only my normal formatting is applied.

**First Visit**
This image shows what the css formatting looks like on the first page visit
Here's [Image](http://www.myphotoshootapp.com/json/css1.png)

**Second Visit**
This image shows what the css formatting looks like when I return to the page (LIKE ITS SUPPOSED TO)
Here's [Image](http://www.myphotoshootapp.com/json/css2.png)

Comment: is this a typos? `$('#ul#photosList').listview('create');` you have `#` before `ul` which isn't an id. Anyway, place `$('#photosList').listview('refresh');` at the end of `$.ajax` call or at the end of **success**.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo, I added $('#photosList').listview('refresh'); to the end of success, now I get the error Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh' in my console.

Comment: are you populating items into active page or another page?

Comment: The function populating the list is ran when a link is clicked on another page, after the onClick event, the function runs, populating the items and forwarding the page.

Comment: has that page been visited before or first view? if first view, you dont need to call enhancement `.listview()`, it will be enhanced automatically. If it has been viewed before, you need to call enhancement on `pagebeforeshow` like this `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page_id", function () { $('#photos').listview('refresh'); });`

Comment: I removed the call to listview and did it on pagebefore show, now my custom formatting is never applied, and every page visit looks like the first image.

Comment: are you using jQM 1.4?

Comment: 1.3.2, i tried it with 1.4 and still the same issue

Comment: 1.3.2 is different than 1.4, not to mention it's still in beta phase.

Comment: Yes, I am using jquery-2.0.3 with jQM 1.3.2, i exchanged the libraries and tried with 1.4.0-beta.1 to see if it fixed anything and it did not.  My page functionality did not seem effected otherwise.

Comment: are you loading your custom css library before jQM css?

Comment: yes, i am adding it before jqm

Comment: loaded it after JQM and there was no change, I added a photo link at the bottom of my original question showing what the console is showing me with all the bloated classes